# Why is nth-child applying to all buttons?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is an [example of my HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/fCFEn/). I can't, for the life of me, figure out why the second rule is applying to all the buttons, and not just the first three.

HTML

```
<div id="test">
<ul>
<li><button>1</button></li>
<li><button>2</button></li>
<li><button>3</button></li>
<li><button>4</button></li>
<li><button>5</button></li>
<li><button>6</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test button
{
    background-color: blue;
}

#test button:nth-child(-n + 3) 
{
    background-color: red;
}

#test button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying `nth-child` to the wrong element: there is only 1 child of each `button`.  You mean to target the `li` elements:

```
#test ul li:nth-child(-n + 3) button
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fCFEn/3/